# Warp image into a circle / arc with css

Tags: css

Is there a reliable CSS way to warp/deform a rectangular *image* into a circle or arc?

I know how to stretch and so on, but applying a shape deform seems to be impossible. Is this right..? Maybe an SVG transform..? Ideally, it would be a transform that is transitionable.

- not talking about using border radius to simulate flat shapes, but actual deform of an image.

Answer (score 5):

**No**, this is not possible yet because only linear transformations are supported by CSS.

However, the answer to this similar question has an example using experimental filters from Adobe to create a sucking effect: [How to use CSS 3d matrix to create a curved deformation effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17870192/how-to-use-3d-matrix-to-create-suck-effect-in-css)

Answer (score 1):

When and how is the rectangle going to transform?  If it's on say, a `:hover` state, then all you need is:

**HTML**

```
<img src="#" class="img-circle" />
```

**CSS**

```
.img-circle:hover {
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/YcacT/

Answer (score 0):

Do you need this one?

```
.circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6AHTb/

The border-radius property is supported in IE9+, Firefox 4+, Chrome, Safari 5+, and Opera.